# C++ type int8_t[20] in delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-xe3

What the equal of

```
int8_t[20]
```

C++ type in Delphi ?

As I know it's byte, but what is [20] ?

Thanks

Comment: The low and high indices does not matter, the important thing is it have 20 elements. You can declare array[100..119] of byte and in memory it's shape is still the same.

Comment: @jachguate, then you might wonder why you're getting out of bounds when you just translated next piece of code which expects the low array bound to be 0.

Comment: TLama, you assume the OP is translating a piece of code but I'm not. I'm just making a point about the memory shape. That said, I'm with you that 0..19 is better for consistency with other languages, but that, at the end, is a matter of taste.

Comment: @jachguate, you might assume it's not a language translation topic, but why would then this question arise ? And, I'm not talking about some consistency, but about case when you're translating a code and in that code is used constant array element indexing. Would you then shift those indexes by 100 instead of declaring the array properly ?

Comment: @TLama properly is not the word, the word is consistently. The array is proper if you declare it to have 20 elements no matter what indexing you use. If you use anything different than 0..19, it is not consistent. And the question arise because the OP is trying to communicate via the network and implementing the data-structures to achieve that communication. AFAIK, it's not a language transaction topic for him, but maybe I'm wrong and he's just translating all the code to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats an array of signed one-byte integers. In C/C++ Arrays all start at index 0, so the valid array-indices run from 0 to 19

Comment: To be more specific for Delphi, it's the `array[0..19] of Shortint`.

Comment: Or `array[0..19] of Int8` for versions of Delphi that support `Int8`, as `Shortint` is now deprecated.